# Giving a ListItem focus from the server on page load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2019

On my aspx page I have the following list items/divs. Is there a way to make the tab in position 1 (divReferralTab) the selected tab on page load by referencing the div or the list item?

```
<div id="mainTabs" class="povMainTabs">
    <ul id="ulMainTabs" runat="server">
        <li id="liRDCTab" runat="server"><a href="#divRDCTab"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRDC" /></a></li>
        <li id="liReferralTab" runat="server"><a href="#divReferralTab" runat="server">Referral</a></li>
        <li id="liContactsTab" runat="server"><a href="#divContactsTab">Holistic/Contact</a></li>            
    </ul>
    <div id="divRDCTab"></div>
    <div id="divReferralTab"></div>
    <div id="divContactsTab"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can try setting the z-index of the control you need first.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: thanks for that, did you mean adding the z-index to the list item or the anchor tag? I tried both but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

If you want the referral "bullet" first then try just listing it first:

```
 <div id="mainTabs" class="povMainTabs">
<ul id="ulMainTabs" runat="server">
    <li id="liReferralTab" runat="server"><a href="#divReferralTab" runat="server">Referral</a></li>
    <li id="liRDCTab" runat="server"><a href="#divRDCTab"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRDC" /></a></li>
    <li id="liContactsTab" runat="server"><a href="#divContactsTab">Holistic/Contact</a></li>            
</ul>
<div id="divRDCTab"></div>
<div id="divReferralTab"></div>
<div id="divContactsTab"></div>
```